# Server Error SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export' This error happened while generating the page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

Getting this error when I try to fetch data via `getServerSideProps`. Please help. Thank you!

Server Error
SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'

This error happened while generating the page. Any console logs will be displayed in the terminal window.

```
/search.js

function Search ({ searchResults }) {
    console.log (searchResults)
    const router = useRouter();
    // console.log(router.query)
    const { location, startDate, endDate, numGuests} = router.query

    const formattedStartDate = format(new Date(startDate), "dd MMMM yy");
    const formattedEndDate = format(new Date(endDate), "dd MMMM yy");

    const range = `${formattedStartDate} - ${formattedEndDate}`

  return (
    <div className=''>
        <Header placeholder={`${location} | ${range} | ${numGuests} Guests`} />
        <main className='flex'>
            {/* left listings side  */}
            <section className='flex-grow pt-14 px-6'>
                <p className='text-xs'>300+ stays - {range} - for {numGuests} guests</p>
                <h1 className='text-3xl font-semibold mt-2 mb-6'>Stays in {location}</h1>

                <div className='hidden lg:inline-flex mb-5 space-x-3 text-gray-800 whitespace-nowrap '>
                    <p className='button'>Cancellation Flexibility</p>
                    <p className='button'>Type of Place</p>
                    <p className='button'>Price</p>
                    <p className='button'>Rooms and Beds</p>
                    <p className='button'>More filters</p>
                </div>
            </section>
        </main>
        <Footer />
    </div>
  );
}

export default Search;

export async function getServerSideProps() {
    const searchResults = await fetch("https://www.jsonkeeper.com/b/W528").then((res) => res.json());

    return {
        props : {
            searchResults,
        },
    };
}
```

```
/package.json

{
  "name": "airbnb-ss",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "date-fns": "^2.29.3",
    "next": "13.0.0",
    "next-transpile-modules": "^9.1.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-date-range": "^1.4.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-icons": "^4.6.0",
    "tailwind-scrollbar-hide": "^1.1.7"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.12",
    "eslint": "8.26.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "13.0.0",
    "postcss": "^8.4.18",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.2.1"
  }
}
```

I am trying to fetch data via `getServerSideProps`

Comment: `export` only works in modules. What is the context of that code?

Comment: so, I am trying to use getServerSideProps to fetch data into next js page. and then pass that fetched data into the component as props.

I did the same in the index.js page with getStaticProps and that worked just fine.

Comment: Can you show us the full error stack trace?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't provide other part of your code, so I can share an example that shows how to fetch data at request time and pre-render the result in next.js properly:

```
function Page({ data }) {
  // Render data...
}

// This gets called on every request
export async function getServerSideProps() {
  // Fetch data from external API
  const res = await fetch(`https://.../data`)
  const data = await res.json()

  // Pass data to the page via props
  return { props: { data } }
}

export default Page
```

You can refer: [Using getServerSideProps to fetch data at request time](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/get-server-side-props#using-getserversideprops-to-fetch-data-at-request-time).

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I updated the rest of the code in that page. I relatively new to nextjs.

Comment: What version of next.js you are using? You also didn't include the project tree and content of package.json file. Next.js has its own project tree structure, e.g. your pages should be in `pages` or `src/pages` and other points you need to consider when working with next.js, as opposed to React.

Also you can read about es-modules-support here to get more information on `export` statement in next.js: https://nextjs.org/blog/next-11-1#es-modules-support

Comment: NextJs version is 13 and the /search.js is inside pages folder. I updated my package.json

Comment: You can check versions of node.js, npm and related stuff installed on your machine. You may find something useful here: https://nextjs.org/docs/upgrading. Also you can simply run `npm install` in order to fix/install required versions of modules and packages by your project. And what command do you use to run your project? AFAIK, some built-in scripts of next.js may have some issues with some internal functions of next.js, like `getServerSideProps`, because of the concrete purposes of certain scripts.